# How to make/use face detection for logging in to website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, face-detection

I want to build a website (just for example, imagine Facebook) where login happens through face detection and matching (the same you see in some laptops and computers nowadays for logging) rather than inserting email id and password. And the same face detection to be used as search feature. If I face the camera towards another person, it will run the face detection, match whatever the values in database are, and returns the found/matched user. So there is any API for that? Do you know any algorithm for it? Please mention as elaborate as possible.

I code in Ruby and Ruby on Rails, and I just want to make this as I want to experiment. I love face detection and matching feature.

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution ready-to-go, but HTML5 [makes it possible](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html).

Comment: This may help as well. http://www.sitepoint.com/detecting-faces-with-ruby-ffi-in-a-nutshell/

Comment: @fotanus - can you tell me how is that possible through HTML5?

Comment: @anmolagrawal correct me if I'm wrong, but the URL I sent you describes an API from javascript for HTML5 to deal with camera objects. I never did this before.

Comment: @fotanus - well, it just allows people to take photos of themselves from the local video camera.

Comment: @anmolagrawal there might be some sass APIs out there (do some googling).  If you want to use a local API, you can try OpenCV of which there is a ruby library (not sure if it supports the `FaceRecognizer` class though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use HTML5 camera support to capture user image and save it to a temporarily url.
2. Send the url to  [faceplusplus](http://www.faceplusplus.com/) api to be recognized

**NB** you will need to train faceplusplus on sign up using the [create person](http://www.faceplusplus.com/personcreate/) api

Comment: ohh my goodness..that looks legit...thanks a ton man!!! I am gonna try  it right now...